# How to convert values of recurring elements row by row to columns?

Tags: unix, text, vim, text-editor

I receive an output of some script that gives rows containing element and it's value.
And there are only 3 elements that repeated with different values.
Want to convert them to columns with element name as column name and then values per column.

I have an output that gathers some server info and put it in file `output.txt` that looks like following:

```
real    0m0.537s
user    0m0.077s
sys 0m0.082s

real    0m0.512s
user    0m0.076s
sys 0m0.083s

real    0m0.498s
user    0m0.072s
sys 0m0.087s
```

So using google I handled it and with the following commands put all values into columns named  real user and sys as following:

```bash
$ sed -i '/^$/d' output.txt
$ awk -F " " '{ print $2 }' output.txt > output2.txt
$ paste -d'\t' - - - < output2.txt | awk 'BEGIN { print "real\tuser\tsys"} {print $0}'
```

so the output looks like this one:

```
real    user    sys
0m0.537s    0m0.077s    0m0.082s
0m0.512s    0m0.076s    0m0.083s
0m0.498s    0m0.072s    0m0.087s
```

So I have 2 questions.

1. How to make column name to fit the column?
2. There should be a way to perform all this ugly stuff using one-liner. Does anyone have this one-liner?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Everything can be a one-liner if you just put the shell commands into a script file.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with `awk`.

The script assumes there are always complete groups of 3 lines as in the example and that `sys` is the last.

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "real\tuser\tsys" }
$1=="real" { r=$2 }
$1=="user" { u=$2 }
$1=="sys" { s=$2; print r "\t" u "\t" s }' output.txt
```

or shorter

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "real\tuser\tsys" }
/^r/ { r=$2 }
/^u/ { u=$2 }
/^s/ { s=$2; print r "\t" u "\t" s }' output.txt
```

If you want a one-liner, remove line breaks and spaces.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "real\tuser\tsys"}/^r/{r=$2}/^u/{u=$2}/^s/{s=$2;print r"\t"u"\t"s}' output.txt
```

Resulting output (tab-separated):

```
real    user    sys
0m0.537s        0m0.077s        0m0.082s
0m0.512s        0m0.076s        0m0.083s
0m0.498s        0m0.072s        0m0.087s
```

How to align the column headings with the data depends on what you need.

Since the string length of the data is 8 characters while the headings are 3 or 4 characters long, the TAB positions (with default TAB width 8) characters are different.

Based on this assumption, one way to fix this is to use two tabs when printing the headings:

```
BEGIN { print "real\t\tuser\t\tsys" }
```

Or you could use `printf` with field with.

```
awk 'function myprint(a, b, c) {
    printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", a, b, c)
}
BEGIN { myprint("real", "user", "sys") }
/^r/ { r=$2 }
/^u/ { u=$2 }
/^s/ { s=$2; myprint(r, u, s) }' output.txt
```

prints

```
real       user       sys
0m0.537s   0m0.077s   0m0.082s
0m0.512s   0m0.076s   0m0.083s
0m0.498s   0m0.072s   0m0.087s
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT. It's just amazing. I swear I'll learn awk after this case

Answer (score 0):

You can format any text into columns like this:

```
$ column -t file.txt
real      user      sys
0m0.537s  0m0.077s  0m0.082s
0m0.512s  0m0.076s  0m0.083s
0m0.498s  0m0.072s  0m0.087s
```

Depending what version of "column" you have (most Linux should be fine), you can probably solve the whole problem like this:

```
$ sed 's/^\S*//' output.txt | xargs -n3 echo | column -t -N real,user,sys
real      user      sys
0m0.537s  0m0.077s  0m0.082s
0m0.512s  0m0.076s  0m0.083s
0m0.498s  0m0.072s  0m0.087s
```

The "sed" removes the first column, the "xargs" groups the values into threes, and the "column" aligns everything and adds the headers.